# Missing artifact error in Wildfly 10 Java EE EAR project

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

I created a Java EE EAR project using the wizard. I have an error in both the pom files of the ear and web subprojects. No erros with the ejb pom file.

This is the error that I get...

Missing artifact org.jboss.ejb3:jboss-ejb3-web:war:1.0.0

Here is the pom file of the ear subproject

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb3</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ear</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <name>jboss-ejb3: EAR Module</name>

    <url>http://wildfly.org</url>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Depend on the ejb module and war so that we can package them -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-web</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ejb</artifactId>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.ear.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Tell Maven we are using Java EE 7 -->
                    <version>7</version>
                    <!-- Use Java EE ear libraries as needed. Java EE ear libraries 
                        are in easy way to package any libraries needed in the ear, and automatically 
                        have any modules (EJB-JARs and WARs) use them -->
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- The WildFly plugin deploys your ear to a local WildFly container -->
            <!-- Due to Maven's lack of intelligence with EARs we need to configure 
                the wildfly maven plugin to skip deployment for all modules. We then enable
                it specifically in the ear module. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <filename>${project.artifactId}.ear</filename>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when invoking mvn. -->
            <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app will need. -->
            <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'deployments' folder. -->
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.ear.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Here is the pom file of the web subproject

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <parent>
      <artifactId>jboss-ejb3</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
   </parent>

   <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-web</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>

   <name>jboss-ejb3: WAR Module</name>

   <url>http://wildfly.org</url>
   <licenses>
      <license>
         <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
         <distribution>repo</distribution>
         <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
      </license>
   </licenses>

   <dependencies>

      <!-- Dependency on the EJB module so we can use it's services if needed -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
         <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ejb</artifactId>
         <type>ejb</type>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
         <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
         <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
         <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

       <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
       <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
       <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss WildFly -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>

   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
               <!-- Java EE 7 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
               <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

The error is occurring in this area of the pom file

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
     <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ejb</artifactId>
     <type>ejb</type>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Please add your parent pom.xml file as well

Answer (score 0):

There must be a modules section in your parent pom file and make sure dependents are under dependencies in order.

```
    <modules>
        <module>core-module</module>
        <module>depends-on-core</module>
        <module>depends-on-core2</module>
        <module>depends-on-depends-on-core</module>
    </modules>
```

After arrangements update maven.